# Get current language of Drupal 8 in javascript?

Tags: 8, javascript

How can I get the language code or name from the Drupal javascript object in a js script ??

I know I can get language using this in php:

> $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();

But I need to have the language in my scripts.

All i got so far is the Drupal Jquery variable

> Var d = Drupal;

Which when printed looks like this.

```
{behaviors: {…}, locale: {…}, throwError: ƒ, attachBehaviors: ƒ, detachBehaviors: ƒ, …}
Ajax:ƒ (base, element, element_settings)
AjaxCommands:ƒ ()
AjaxError:ƒ (xmlhttp, uri, customMessage)
ProgressBar:ƒ (id, updateCallback, method, errorCallback)
Views:{parseQueryString: ƒ, parseViewArgs: ƒ, pathPortion: ƒ, getPath: ƒ}
ajax:ƒ (settings)
attachBehaviors:ƒ (context, settings)
behaviors:{autologout: {…}, drupalDisplace: {…}, responsiveImageAJAX: {…}, AJAX: {…}, activeLinks: {…}, …}
checkPlain:ƒ (str)
debounce:ƒ (func, wait, immediate)
detachBehaviors:ƒ (context, settings, trigger)
dialog:ƒ (element, options)
displace:ƒ displace(broadcast)
encodePath:ƒ (item)
formatPlural:ƒ (count, singular, plural, args, options)
formatString:ƒ (str, args)
history:{fetchTimestamps: ƒ, getLastRead: ƒ, markAsRead: ƒ, needsServerCheck: ƒ}
locale:{}
stringReplace:ƒ (str, args, keys)
t:ƒ (str, args, options)
theme:ƒ (func)
throwError:ƒ (error)
url:ƒ (path)
views:{instances: {…}, ajaxView: ƒ}
__proto__:Object
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add whatever you want to the `javascript` via your `THEMENAME.theme`:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(array &$variables) {
    $variables['#attached']['drupalSettings']['language'] = $language;
}
```

After that, you can call it in `javascript`:

```
console.log(drupalSettings.language);
```

**Edit**

You need to enable `drupalSettings` as a dependency in your `THEMENAME.libraries.yml`:

```
frontend:
  dependencies:
    - core/drupalSettings
```

Comment: See answer below, this is already provided by Drupal core, so this answer is out of date and adding data we don't need

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Probably my answer from 2017 is a little bit outdated ;-)
Good to know that there is a better solution.

Answer (score 36):

In pages with the core/drupalSettings library included, it seems to be pretty reliably available through the path:

```
var langCode = drupalSettings.path.currentLanguage;
```

Comment: This is such a better answer.